# What is worst case Space complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, probability, space-complexity

If input of our algo is an array A of size n, and we have to copy it in another array B.

What is the worst case space efficiency in theta n notation of this algo?

I believe the worst case in big O notation is O(nlogM) where n is the number of elements in array A and logM is the space taken by the largest integer in bits. But i cant figure out the worst case space efficiency in theta notation.

I think it should be:
Theta( summation i=1 to n (logni))

Where logni is the space taken by an integer at ith index of array A.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your algorithm? Also, are you counting how many bits of memory it needs or how many words of memory it needs?

Comment: So, given an array A of size 1 to n i m trying to find kth largest elemnt. For doing so i am randmly pickng a elemnt of A and thn checkng if tht elemnt is the kth largest elemnt. I m returnng my algo if the elemnt is indeed kth largest, whereas if not thn i m adding it in a set1 such that i wont sample tht elemnt again when i randomly pick an element of A to check if its the kth largest. in worst case i would’ve to iterate over all n possible elements of A to get kth largest element. I.e. i would have to put all n elements in the set set1. In such case wht would be worst case space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

**Worst case complexity** : The running time for any given size input
will be lower than the upper bound except possibly for some values of
the input where the maximum is reached.

Comment: This answer seems to address *time* complexity rather than *space* complexity.